# Xcode Storyboards now only show outlines

Tags: xcode

All of my storyboards have now gone blank.  All I get is an outline of the elements.

the Main storyboard is worse, it is 100% black and has the image of an iPhone

How do I repair?  Using Xcode 10.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Did you find something? I am still stuck here

Comment: went away when I upgraded Xcode.  Now working on Xcode 11.  Not had any similar issues since.

Comment: For me, I deleted the xcode and reistalled again. I was on Xcode10